# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C in Linux

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run this program by taking input from the user and I'm getting a ***Segmentation fault (core dumped)*** error. Can anyone help me to find out why this error is occurring and how can I fix this error? My code is given below:

```
// C program to remove the occurrences of a specific char from the given string.

#include <stdio.h>

char *squeeze(char *a[], int b){

    int i,j;

    for(i=j=0; *(*a+i)='\0';i++){

       if(*(*a+i)!=b)
           *(*a+j++)=*(*a+i);
    }
    *(*a+j)='\0';

    return *a;
}

void main(){

    char *c[1];
    char d[2];
    int e;

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    scanf("%s",*c);
    printf("Enter the character to delete: ");
    scanf("%c",d);
    e=d[0];

    printf("Resulting string is:%s.\n",squeeze(c,e));
}
```

Comment: `char *c[1];` and `scanf("%s",*c);` are not valid together read about how to handle string in C.

Comment: Compile the code with debugging symbols, and run the code inside a debugger. Optionally use `valgrind`. Treat compiler warnings as if they are errors.

Comment: Enable the warnings while compiling the code. For gcc, -Wall is for enabling all the warning.

Comment: `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors on gcc/clang.
Why is `b` an `int`?

Comment: Something else you probably want to do is take a basic course in C.  Your usage of pointers and arrays simply isn't correct for what you're trying to do - it's actually more complex than you need it to be.  Secondly, you need to understand the differences and similarities between arrays and pointers.  Use of them sometimes looks very similar, but in actuality they are quite different.

Comment: @Inrin `b` as an `int` likely makes for slightly more efficient code that `char b`.  Not a big issue, even is `char b` seems called for.

Comment: @dgnuff Comments that address issues of the code and post - not the poster are  more objective and usually better received.

Comment: sure, but as she/he is a beginner, I thought semantics over performance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dereferencing pointers without pointing them at a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294631/dereferencing-pointers-without-pointing-them-at-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems in your code. First, as pointed out in the comments, your declaration of `c` as an array of `char *` length one is wrong.  Declare it as an array of char or some max length.  The will make the squeeze code simpler, with less dereferences.  Next your for loop inside of squeeze is wrong, you have an assignment statement there in the middle, when you really want to check for inequality.  Your second scanf needs a space in it to get rid of the white space character leftover in the input buffer.  So, making these changes, your code should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *squeeze(char *a, int b){

                int i,j;

                for(i=j=0; *(a+i) != '\0';i++){
                    if(*(a+i)!=b)
                        *(a+j++)=*(a+i);
                }
                *(a+j)='\0';

                return a;
}

int main() {

                char c[100] = {0};
                char d[2];
                int e;

                printf("Enter the string: ");
                scanf("%99s",c);
                printf("Enter the character to delete: ");
                scanf(" %c",d);
                e=d[0];

                printf("Resulting string is: %s.\n",squeeze(c,e));
}
```

**EDIT:** Specify string length with scanf when reading in `c`.

Comment: @chux very true. Should also check the return code to make sure you got something back.

Answer (score 0):

```
// C program to remove the occurrences of a specific char from the given string.

#include<stdio.h>

char * squeeze(char a[], char b){

for(i=0; a[i]!='\0';i++){
    if(a[i]==b){
      a[i]=a[i+1];
    while(a[i++]!='\0'){
      a[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    }
}
    return a;
}

int main(){

    char c[50];
    char d;

    printf("Enter the string:");

    scanf("%s",c);
    printf("Enter the character to delete:");//add \n 

    scanf(" %c",&d);


    printf("Resulting string is:%s\n",squeeze(c,d));

    return 0;
}
```